# relationships cakephp makes awful array

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I am using cakephp 2.3.4. I have a databases table vendors and a table products. They both have many to many relation shop with each other. My issue is that once the array is returned for my vendors that carry some products, that arrays format is little funky and it is hard for me to resolve it properly. Here is what I have got

Vendor Model:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Vendor extends AppModel {



/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $actsAs = array('Search.Searchable');

    public $filterArgs = array(
        array('name' => 'vendor_name', 'type' => 'query','method'=>'filterVendor'),
        array('name' => 'is_finalized', 'type' => 'string'),

    );

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Product' => array(
            'className' => 'Product',
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Product' => array(
            'className' => 'Product',
            'foreignKey' => 'vendor_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

  /*  public function __construct($id = false,$table = null,$ids = null) {
        $this->statuses = array(
            'open' => __('Open',true),
            'closed' => __('Closed',true),
        );
        $this->categories = array(
            'bug' => __('bug',true),
            'support' => __('support',true),
            'technical' => __('technical',true),
            'other' => __('other',true),
        );
        parent::__construct($id,$table,$ids);

    }
*/


    public function filterVendor($data = array()) {
        $filter = $data['vendor_name'];
        if(empty($filter))
        {
            return array();
        }
        $cond = array(
            'OR' => array(
                $this->alias . '.vendor_name LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%',
            ));
        return $cond;
    }

}
```

issue is that in my view file I get the array of products like this

```
  <?php
        $i = 0;
        Debugger::dump($vendor['Product']);
        foreach ($vendor['Product'] as $product):
            if ( !is_null($product['id'])):
                Debugger::dump($product['id']);
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $product['id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['vendor_id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['sku']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['product_name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['product_weight']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['product_dimenssions']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['product_quantity']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['product_quantity_sold']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['product_quantity_returned']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['product_cost_price']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['product_list_price']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['product_map_price']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['product_special_instructions']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['is_fragile']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['is_downloadable']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['is_always_in_stock']; ?></td>
                    <td class="actions">
                        <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'view', $product['id'])); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'edit', $product['id'])); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'delete', $product['id']), null, __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $product['id'])); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; endforeach; ?>
```

and the debugger statement above will give us this

```
array(
    'id' => '3',
    'vendor_id' => '6',
    'sku' => '5327',
    'product_name' => '4' Bamboo Palm Silk Tree',
    'product_weight' => null,
    'product_dimenssions' => '4'x36"x36"',
    'product_quantity' => null,
    'product_quantity_sold' => null,
    'product_quantity_returned' => null,
    'product_cost_price' => null,
    'product_list_price' => null,
    'product_map_price' => null,
    'product_special_instructions' => '',
    'is_fragile' => true,
    'is_downloadable' => false,
    'is_always_in_stock' => false,
    'category' => null,
    'product_category' => null,
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => '3',
        'vendor_id' => '6',
        'sku' => '5327',
        'product_name' => '4' Bamboo Palm Silk Tree',
        'product_weight' => null,
        'product_dimenssions' => '4'x36"x36"',
        'product_quantity' => null,
        'product_quantity_sold' => null,
        'product_quantity_returned' => null,
        'product_cost_price' => null,
        'product_list_price' => null,
        'product_map_price' => null,
        'product_special_instructions' => '',
        'is_fragile' => true,
        'is_downloadable' => false,
        'is_always_in_stock' => false,
        'category' => null,
        'product_category' => null
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'id' => '4',
        'vendor_id' => '6',
        'sku' => '5254',
        'product_name' => '75" Bamboo Silk Tree',
        'product_weight' => null,
        'product_dimenssions' => 'Height: 75 in Width: 33 in Depth: 33 in Pot size: W: 7 in, H: 6 in Trunk type: Natural Number of leaves: 1440',
        'product_quantity' => null,
        'product_quantity_sold' => null,
        'product_quantity_returned' => null,
        'product_cost_price' => null,
        'product_list_price' => null,
        'product_map_price' => null,
        'product_special_instructions' => '',
        'is_fragile' => true,
        'is_downloadable' => false,
        'is_always_in_stock' => false,
        'category' => null,
        'product_category' => null
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'id' => '5',
        'vendor_id' => '6',
        'sku' => '5250',
        'product_name' => '7' Bamboo Palm Silk Tree',
        'product_weight' => null,
        'product_dimenssions' => 'Height: 7 ft Width: 43 in Depth: 43 in Pot size: W: 7 in, H: 6 in Trunk type: Natural Number of leaves: 1542',
        'product_quantity' => null,
        'product_quantity_sold' => null,
        'product_quantity_returned' => null,
        'product_cost_price' => null,
        'product_list_price' => null,
        'product_map_price' => null,
        'product_special_instructions' => '',
        'is_fragile' => true,
        'is_downloadable' => false,
        'is_always_in_stock' => false,
        'category' => null,
        'product_category' => null
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'id' => '6',
        'vendor_id' => '6',
        'sku' => '0514',
        'product_name' => 'Bamboo Square Decorative Planters (Set of 4)',
        'product_weight' => null,
        'product_dimenssions' => 'Small Size Dimensions H: 8 in, W: 8 in, D: 8 in Medium Size Dimensions H: 10 in, W: 10 in, D: 10 in Large Size Dimensions H: 12 in, W: 12 in, D: 12 in Extra Large Size Dimensions H: 14 in, W: 13.75 in, D: 13.75',
        'product_quantity' => null,
        'product_quantity_sold' => null,
        'product_quantity_returned' => null,
        'product_cost_price' => null,
        'product_list_price' => null,
        'product_map_price' => null,
        'product_special_instructions' => '',
        'is_fragile' => true,
        'is_downloadable' => false,
        'is_always_in_stock' => false,
        'category' => null,
        'product_category' => null
    ),
)
```

you see the format of the array is pretty messed up as the actual products sub array doesnt start under a property name rather it just starts with an int and then there are some other properties that are included with the structure of the array.

My question is that is this something that cake is doing or can I fix that. If I can how?
thanks

Comment: _(1)_ Your database design is not representing a many-to-many relationship between products and vendors. @deepak-bansal answer shows the Cakephp solution. In database design, many-to-many requires a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). _(2)_ Assuming your database design is correct, you cannot use the same alias in your relationship definitions. See [aliases for each model must be unique across the app.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#relationship-types) You have aliased both relations to the Product model as Product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cakephp we can implement Many to Many (HABTM) using different structure. For HABTM you need 3 tables

1. products
2. vendors
3. products_vendors

Also you need a relationship define like

In Product Model

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Vendor' => array(
        'className' => 'Vendor',
        'joinTable' => 'products_vendors',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'vendor_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting'
    )
);
```

In Vendor Model

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Product' => array(
        'className' => 'Product',
        'joinTable' => 'products_vendors',
        'foreignKey' => 'vendor_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'product_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting'
    )
);
```

This will give you proper results.

Comment: hmm..I am a bit of pickle then as I would need to create that product_vendors table and I have a lot of data